# Java усовершенствовать mergesort (деление не пополам, а любое число)

Tags: java

Есть сортировка слиянием.

Нужно ее усовершенствовать, сделать так что б список делился на любое число t>2
предлагается добавить:

```
class TWayMergeSort {
private static int t = 100;
public static void setT(int tt) {
    if(tt>1) t = tt;
    else t = 2;
}
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T> > void sort(List<T> array) {
```

Основная сложность в функции merge.

Кому не сложно, пару советов...

Сама сортировка, которую нужно изменить:

```
ublic class MergeSort {
 public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> array) {

     mSort (array, array.size());
}

public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void mSort (List<T> list, int n){
     if (list.size()<2){
         return;
     }

     int midle = list.size()/2;
     List<T> l = new ArrayList<T>();
     List<T> r = new ArrayList<T>();
     int i = 0;

     while (i < midle){
        l.add(list.get(i));
        i++;
     }

    while (i < n){
        r.add(list.get(i));
        i++;
    }

    mSort(l, midle);
    mSort(r, n - midle);

    merge (list, l , r, midle, n - midle);

}

public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void merge (List<T> a, List<T> l, List<T> r, int left, int right){

     int i=0, j=0, k=0;
     a.clear();

     while ( i < left && j < right){
         if (l.get(i).compareTo(r.get(j)) < 0  ){
             a.add(l.get(i));
         }
         else {
             a.add(r.get(i));
         }
     }

     while (i < left){
         a.add(l.get(i));
         i++;
     }

     while (j < right){
         a.add(r.get(j));
         j++;
     }


}

public static ArrayList<Integer> readFile (String name){
    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileReader fr = null;

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    try{
        fr = new FileReader(name);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String sCurentLine;

        while((sCurentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(sCurentLine));

        }

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try{
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
            if (fr != null)
                fr.close();
        } catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: int midle = list.size()/2; тут одно число поменять надо, нет?

Comment: да, вместо 2, теперь число t, которое может любым 3, 5 ...

Comment: она загружается в public static void setT(int tt)  из тестирующего класса

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko нет, тут не одно число добавить. Тут надо делать на t равных частей, и затем эти части ( которых будет больше чем 2) нужно уметь мержить.

Comment: да, раньше делили пополам, теперь нужно уметь на 3, 4, 5 ... смотря какое t придет из класса Test

Comment: @Ponoptikum а вы сами что-либо пробовали сделать? Попытки какие-нибудь

Comment: @AndrewBystrov а зачем это вообще нужно? Разделив на 3 части, при слиянии, придется проводить два сравнение вместо одного

Comment: задание такое... усложнить жизнь, размять мозг. сам пробую, разделять рекурсивно массив на нужно число не сложно, а вот потом как склеивать, при этом сортируя, уже ломаю голову